# Connectedness of preimage of morphisms of algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism between smooth complex algebraic varieties and $S \subset Y$ a closed connected smooth subvariety such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected for all $y \in S$. Is $f^{-1}(S)$ connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not correct. Let $X\subset\Bbb A^2$ be $V(xy-1)\sqcup V(x,y)$, let $S=Y=\Bbb A^1$, and let $f:X\to Y$ be the projection. Then every fiber is a singleton, hence connected, but $X$ is disconnected.

If you insist that varieties should be irreducible, one can get the same example by taking $S$ to be $V(y,z)\subset\Bbb A^3$ and the map $f$ to be the map $\Bbb A^2\to\Bbb A^3$ sending $(x,y)\mapsto (x,x(xy-1),y(xy-1))$. The fiber over every point of $S$ is again a singleton, but the preimage of $S$ is disconnected.

If you're interested in a situation where the answer is yes, you may consult [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3606671/21412) which shows that when you add some assumptions, everything works.